# Share live graph from Graphite Server

Tags: graphite

I have a requirement to share live (timely updating) graphs from Graphite in form of a HTML tag (inline). I know that, Graphite provides a static URL, representing snapshot, of the graph.

How I can achieve this with Graphite? Is there any open-source plugin for this?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved with a little bit of JavaScript and the default Graphite PNG output. If you're comfortable with JavaScript there are other frameworks (D3, Rickshaw, etc) that will automatically refresh the data but you'll have to perform the initial coding.

Comment: Ok.. I thought there should be a library which can do this.